# Vcpkg 2 different behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, vcpkg

I am working on two similar projects which both utilize **Vcpkg** integration with Visual Studio 2022. While one of the projects compiles successfully, the other is experiencing issues with including the Boost header files. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appeared to be a glitch. By moving the

```
 <PropertyGroup Label="Vcpkg"> 
<VcpkgEnableManifest>true</VcpkgEnableManifest> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

section from the bottom to the top of the vcxproj file, I was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it  to change the thread's status to Answered. Just a reminder :)